# Plücker matrix - Rank 2 proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projective-geometry, matrix-rank

How can I proof that the Plücker matrix of the form

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -L_{01} & -L_{02} & -L_{03}\\
L_{01} & 0 & -L_{12} & -L_{13}\\
L_{02} & L_{12} & 0 & -L_{23}\\
L_{03} & L_{13} & L_{23} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

has only rank 2?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that a generic 4x4 skew-symmetric matrix would have rank 2, but that a generic 4x4 skew-symmetric matrix in the form of $uv^T−vu^T$ has rank 2. To prove this, suppose $u,v$ be linearly independent. Can you show that $u,v$ are in the image of $uv^T−vu^T$? So, what is the image of $uv^T−vu^T$?

Comment: To me, it is obvious it has Rank 2 because it is decomposed with _two_ vectors, $v$ and $u$.

Comment: How can a skew symmetric matrix of even dimensions be singular

Comment: @Upstart What do you mean? The zero matrix, for instance, is always singular, regardless of the parity of its dimension.

Comment: Except the zero matrix.The eigenvalues of a skew symmetric matrices are purely imaginary and occur in pairs

Comment: @Upstart I don't see the relevance of being nonzero here. E.g. $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}\oplus0$ is nonzero but singular. In general, the direct sum of any square matrix (whether it is singular or skew-symmetric is unimportant) and a zero matrix (of odd or even dimension) is always singular. I also don't see the relevance of your question to my answer. Would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The elmenets of L are not arbitrary. They can be written as $L_{ij} = A_iB_j - B_iA_j.$ with any two distinct points A, B the line contains. The answer lies in the Grassman-Plücker relations. The simple proof is to compute
$L_{01} L_{23} -L_{02} L_{13}+L_{03} L_{12}=0$
(just expand by hand)

An geometric, although less obvious way to see this is that the moment and direction vectors must be orthogonal (which is exactly the statement above) see Wkipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_matrix#Geometric_interpretation Section "Geometric interpretation"

P.S: What's called "displacement" in the article is really a vector pointing in the direction from B to A...